# SSIS - How start connection manager at runtime?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

### Problem

We are in the need provide the password to the connection manager in run-time.

### Description

Given the firm policy on password management we fetch the necessary credentials per package in a script task and it's all fine and good if we use those credentials to authenticate to a Rest API for example, but as Connection Managers need the password set on package creation, we are looking for a way to modify or create a connection manager whilst the package runs.

### Question

Is there a way to create or modify a Connection Manager from the package itself (i.e. from a Script Task)?

### Example and expected result

Now we have our connection managers created as we normally do:

[image]

We want to be able to create the 'Other DB' connection manager from a set of variables:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question here? You've given a problem, you've given a description of your current set up, but you haven't asked anything.

Comment: our problem is we need to modify or create a connect manager after we fetch the password with a script task, and save it to a variable.

Comment: Yes, but what is you're question...? SSIS has expressions to set properties of objects, what's wrong with those?

Comment: I added what we hope to accomplish, I looked into SSIS expressions but the connection manager creation does not accept this as a username or password.

Comment: *"but the connection manager creation does not accept this as a username or password"* Connection Managers are more than happy to have their connection string set from a variable. That's how you create project connection managers that change depending on the environement, for example.

Comment: I apologize, one of my team members was able to make this work with your recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on "Our DB" and select properties.

In the properties menu, you're going to be looking for the `Expressions...` bit and there you need to either specify the full connection string or just substitute the password and username.

Furthermore, you're now going to have have to specify that the Connection Manager, still in the properties menu, has DelayValidation to True.

Every task that uses the Connection Manager (data flow, etc) will also need to have the Delay Validation property set to True as well.

A cleaner method, assuming 2012+ is to deploy to the SSISDB and Configure the project/package from that interface. The password is encrypted within the database and is not exposed. You simply map the username and password property from there. For ease, I encourage people to use the Environment Variables within the SSISDB as it allows things like updating the password value when it changes in a single location and all the using packages get the new value when they start.

Comment: thanks for the recommendations, we will explore all options.